# i want it so when i click on dropdown options and when click on a text a image appear right next to it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I would like to make a dropdown UI so when i want to select a mape on the dropdown and i choose a map then a image of that map appears next to the dropdown UI. i dont mean to put it on the DropDown Ui it self if thats what your thinking. so i need to make it when i click on a option the code will change the image.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class DropMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite[] map;

    public Image maps;

    public Camera cam;

    public Dropdown ddFruites;

    public void DropDownCheck(int value)
    {

        if (value == 0)
        {
            
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        ddFruites.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate
        {


            ddFruitesValueChangedHappened(ddFruites);
        });
    }
    public void ddFruitesValueChangedHappened(Dropdown sender)
    {
        map.sprite = maps[sender.value];
    }

  
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags. `unityscript` is/was a JavaScript flavor like language used in previous Unity version and is long deprecated by now.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you put an image right next to your dropdown. First create an array of sprite and image. To change sprite of your image.

```
public Sprite[] maps;
public Image map;
```

then use them like:

```
public void ddFruitesValueChangedHappened(Dropdown sender)
{
    map.sprite=maps[sender.value];
}
```

Comment: Hello @FatihAslan. Thanks for your response, on your code it says ''public Sprite[]'' and the "public Image map''. The public image, is the image it self or is it the image UI . and the Sprite maps is the name of the Sprite and the image inside of sprite?
Changed the code above

Comment: @PROHGF attach your map sprites to your `Sprite[] maps` in unity inspector. And your ui map image to your `Image map` in unity inspector.